# Is there a resource to help convert Prototype JavaScript to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, prototypejs

I have extensively used Prototype before and it helped us add considerable interactivity to our web applications. However we are looking at making the move to use jQuery in order to standardize on something better supported in Visual Studio.

I understand that we can use the jQuery.noConflict to run it alongside Prototype, but we would like to avoid having users need to download both libraries to use our website.

So, is there a good resource that can help us move old scripts from Prototype to jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really help you too much with your question, other than to say that I haven't heard of any such tool, and that I'd be really surprised if one actually existed.

While I think jQuery is a great library, and that you're right to be wanting to only use one library, just remember that the cost of you changing over all your scripts is going to be many many hours of work. The cost of your users downloading an extra 30kb of scripts is going to be roughly 0.3 seconds. Perhaps try to slowly phase out Prototype and only refactor your existing pages when a) you have to, or b) if you've got nothing better to do.

Answer (score 1):

Falkayn,

There is no automated process available for conversion of JavaScipt code written against one JS library to another one. Moreover there cannot be one. Different libraries implement different proramming models as well as they arrange their APIs in different manner.

So, before you have found a solution to your problem now ask yourself a question: Am I going to convert my jQuery code once another even "cooler" "X-type" JavaScript library became available?
If your answer is no, take your time and convert the code manually no mater how long will it take. In case you answer "yes" don't convert the code at all.

So it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for your input. I was looking for more of a syntax comparison than anything automated, but nickf makes a good point in that the real cost need not be too great. We only used Prototype on a few pages that really needed a high level of interactivity, so as long as mind out Ps and Qs it should not hurt to use jQuery everywhere else.