# Convert from prototype to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Is there a consistent and generic way to convert prototype code to jQuery?

I'm not asking **how to convert specific code** like:
From:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () { 
    /*code*/ 
});
```

To:

```
$(function(e){ 
    /*code*/ 
});
```

But how to convert **any code** from prototype to jQuery.
I am not sure this is possible, but any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

**Update:**
I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256768/is-there-a-resource-to-help-convert-prototype-javascript-to-jquery) but this is 4 years old..
You know, a question like (how to load data from the server without reloading the page) in 1990 would have an obvious answer: **you cannot**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256768/is-there-a-resource-to-help-convert-prototype-javascript-to-jquery

Comment: @ts. I seen that question, but since it's 4 years old, I was thinking maybe things have changed meanwhile...

Comment: @skafandri I really fail to see why a tool of this type to ever be created - for one .... as you have already pointed out both libraries change - and they change a lot ... I would suggest that this is going to be a manual task ..

Comment: @ManseUK Better to be sure the answer is **no** than to keep wondering *what if it exists*..

Comment: Actually, from technical point of view, developing such a tool is possible, but who would do it?...

Comment: You're answering (a lot) your own questions, and commenting on them as well? You know there is a Q&A function right?

Answer (score 2):

I realized such a tool could not exist

Comment: Yeah! I was highly expecting this kind of answers... Anyway! I tried :)